# Angular ag-grid refresh from another component

Tags: angular, refresh, ag-grid-angular

I'm facing a problem with refreshing cells with the component ag-grid even with the documentation. I have a component which display ag-grid, and the first column display buttons to make operations on the differents rows.
[image]

```
{
        headerName: 'Actions', field: '', cellRendererFramework: ActionButtonsComponent, width: 140
      },
      {...
```

Buttons are rendered with cellRendererFramework. When i click on the 'valid' button, it changes the value 'En Cours' to 'Terminé' in database very well but i want to refresh the cell at the same time.

Actually, the click method is the following one :

```
terminerDeveloppement(devId: number) {
   this.developpementService.terminerDeveloppement(devId).subscribe(res => {
     //not working cause gridApi is a parent component attribut
     //this.gridApi.refreshCells();

   });
 }
```

I really don't know how to solve this.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a data service to refresh the cells after updating database.
This tutorial is very good : https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/

The real problem was trying to update data of the grid outside the component and this solution is working well.

Answer (score 1):

I think invoke ParentComponent in `ActionButtonsComponent`.
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#example-rendering-using-angular-components

```
@Component({
  selector: 'avitve-button-cell',
  template: `
    <span
      ><button
        style="height: 20px"
        (click)="invokeParentMethod()"
      >
        Invoke Parent
      </button></span
    >
  `})
export class ActionButtonsComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  public params: any;

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
  }

  public invokeParentMethod() {
    // this.params.data has current row value not cell
    this.params.context.componentParent.methodFromParent(this.params.data);
  }

  refresh(): boolean {
    return false;
  }
}
```

at ParentComponent

```
<ag-grid-angular
        [context]="context"
></ag-grid-angular>
```

```
  this.context = { compnentParent: this}
  methodFromParent(rowData) {
   // get devId from rowData
 
   this.developpementService.terminerDeveloppement(devId).subscribe(res => {
     this.gridApi.refreshCells();
   });
  }
```

If you can't change, you'll try edit rowData directly. rowData(this.params.data) has all  row value.
or use `this.gridApi.setRowData(res)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i used a data service with the observer patern to refresh data in the grid and works fine :)